# _events is null or not an object error only when compilation debug="false"

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been creating and using a page on the development environment for awhile, it is a search oriented page that is heavy on the ASP.NET AJAX controls.  I've recently tried to move this to production, however, whenever I set the value in the Web.Config file:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

Clicking on anything on the page which would result in an UpdatePanel update or an AJAX postback causes a JavaScript error to be thrown:

```
Message: '_events' is null or not an object
Line: 5
Char: 36005
```

However, as soon as I set:

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

again, everything works perfectly again.

Does anyone have any tips as to what I might check in my code that would be causing this error, and why it is that the setting of this debug="false" in the compilation param causes this?

It is unlikely that setting debug="false" is the direct cause of this error, but maybe if I got some details about what debug="false" might be doing differently, I might know better where to look inside my ASP.Net/AJAX code to fix the problem.

Edit: I've tried this both in IE and in Firefox with the same results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the AjaxControlToolkit that was addressed in the next version.  Upon updating, these errors were resolved.